# What image resampling technique is used in imagecopyresampled()?

Tags: php, image

I'm trying to figure out what's the algorithm behind [imagecopyresampled()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.imagecopyresampled.php) ? Is it bicubic interpolation, cubic interpolation or any other ?

It's not in the documentation and I can't seem to find it anywhere!

Comment: Check out its source code: [PHP function](https://github.com/php/php-src/blob/4a2e40bb861bc3cf5fb6863e57486ed60316e97c/ext/gd/gd.c#L1816), [declaration](https://github.com/php/php-src/blob/0437aa2abf1eb494e4555d7d4dfbdbf566a59bdc/ext/gd/libgd/gd.h#L682), [definition](https://github.com/php/php-src/blob/0437aa2abf1eb494e4555d7d4dfbdbf566a59bdc/ext/gd/libgd/gd.c#L2448).

Comment: There are no comments in the code identified by @Spooky to help. The code iterates across multiple pixels in the input for down-sampling and applies a non-linear contribution from these pixels. You'll need to work out the contribution from each to determine the interpolation function.

Comment: @Pekka Yeah :/ Plus this is C and I've never read that language before. I *think* that it's bi-linear interpolation but not positive.